# Getting error "Callable returned null" when using RxJava2

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am using RxJava2 in my android project.

I am using the following code to create the `Observable`

```
public Observable<AlbumDetails> loadAlbumFromAlbumId(final String albumId) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<AlbumDetails>() {
        @Override
        public AlbumDetails call() throws Exception {
             AlbumDetails albumDetails = getAlbumDetails(albumId);     
             return albumDetails;   
       });
}
```

From the observable, I am getting following error in the onError method of DisposableObserver

`Callable returned null`

This didn't use to happend when using RxJava.

Comment: not giving an error at compilation time neither in debug apk but give you a shot at released apk.

Answer (score 21):

I used to have code like this:

```
Observable<R> obs = Observable.fromCallable(this::work);
```

work() may return `null` and as you noted, RxJava 2 is not happy with this.

#### Method 1

```
Observable<R> obs = Maybe.fromCallable(this::work).toObservable();
```

In this way, the end consumer - the observer - will only kick off if work() had anything to return. If work() returned null then it's the same as subscribing to an empty Observer; nothing happens.

#### Method 2

```
Observable<R> obs = Observable.create(e -> {
    R r = work();

    if (r != null) {
        e.onNext(r);
    }

    e.onComplete();
});
```

#### Method 3:

Wrapping each emission in an `Optional` = bad idea for a number of reasons.

Mainly because I only use Optional in my APIs if it is expected and sort of the "normal" scenario that you get a null every now and then. If null is not expected or very rare, maybe as a direct result of another API call done by the same consumer, then I return null and let the consumer deal with it in these exceptional cases rather than having every consumer deal with Optional all over the place.

Answer (score 9):

As given here in the wiki :

[What's Different in 2.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#nulls)

RxJava 2.x no longer accepts null values. Having null as a stream element causes a `NullPointerException` immediately and thus the onError method is called.

This has been done mainly to avoid crashes due to `NullPointerException` in the apps.

I solved this by a rather simple approach. 
I checked if the value was null, and if it was, I replaced the null with a placeholder object.

Other more sophisticated approaches also exist that tackle this issue, but for my use case, this simple approach was enough.

Answer (score 3):

RxJava 2.x no longer accepts null values without implementing error handler

**example**

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> null)
    .subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);

Observable.just(1).map(v -> null)
    .subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

**Solution for your questian**

When you call/subscribe this method do like bellow

```
Observable<AlbumDetails> testObservable= Observable.create(emitter -> { ... });
testObservable.subscribe(t -> System.out.print(t),Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `getAlbumDetails(albumId)` method returns `null` in case of the data is not available or error, and you are willing to just gracefully complete your stream in such situation, you could use something like this:

```
public Observable<AlbumDetails> loadAlbumFromAlbumId(String albumId) {
    return Maybe.fromCallable(() -> getAlbumDetails(albumId))
        .onErrorComplete()
        .toObservable();
};
```

I've replaced the anonymous class with lambda for better readability, but you can keep it as is, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap the return value in an Optional (Java 8). And the map that within your subscription using optional.isPresent() and optional.get().

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this workaround :

First created a wrapper class:

```
class NullableObject<T>(val value: T?)
```

Then created an extension function for Single like this:

```
inline fun <T> runInSingle(
        crossinline block: () -> T,
        crossinline callback: (T?) -> Unit,
        crossinline onError: (Throwable) -> Unit) {

   Single.fromCallable {
      return@fromCallable block().toNullableObject()
   }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
           .subscribe { result, error ->
              if (error != null) {
                 onError(error)
              } else {
                 callback(result.value)
              }
           }
}

fun <T> T.toNullableObject(): NullableObject<T> = NullableObject(this)
```

How to use :

```
runInSingle({
         doSomethingInBackgroundWhichMayReturnNull()
      }, { result ->
         if(result != null) {
           doSomethingWithTheNonNullResult()
         } else {
           doSomethingWithTheNullResult()
         }
      }, { error ->
         error.printStackTrace()
      })
```